# Can I exclude maven plugin folders from the target folder?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, target

I'm using some plugins to build my maven project.

During the "install" phase, maven create plugin directories inside my target folder, but I don't need them.

There's an option to avoid the creation of this directories that allows me to continue to use those plugins? 
In my case are 'maven-archiver' and 'surefire' (that is also empty after the building).

`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.hopom</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.hopom.mytools</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyParser</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>MyParser</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org/MyParser</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>zxing</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>zxing-javase</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcprov</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov</artifactId>
      <version>jdk15on-147</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target</directory>
    <finalName>MyParser-1.0</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                  <mainClass>parser.MyParser</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <finalName>MyParser</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>parser.MyParser</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <finalName>MyParser</finalName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/home/michele/workspace/Migration/mytools/MyParser/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>`
```

Comment: post your effective pom.xml `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: don't see anything that generates that directory, can you tell me what is the content inside it

Comment: 'surefire' is always empty. 'maven-archiver' contains a file called pom.properties that seems a simple manifest, but I don't know why is created, I don't use those plugins after compilation.

Comment: I thought you said it creates `plugin` directory

Comment: yes, simple directories with plugin names, in the target directory

Answer (score 1):

those directories (`surefire` & `maven-archiver`) gets generated by surefire and archiver plugin respectively

when you do `mvn clean install` it goes through following phases

```
validate, clean, compile, test, package, install
```

these two plugin are by default tied to

```
phases surefire - > test
```

and

```
archiver -> package
```

so those plugins gets executed and that generates these directories, if you don't want their execution you can skip sure-fire's execution that will stop running any test cases by configuring your pom.xml following way

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

to stop export of test result you can either set it to output to some other directory by setting [`reportsDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory) property or you can stop generating xml reports using [`disableXmlReports`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#disableXmlReport) property

Comment: Yes, I already know that. I'm trying to avoid the creation of them and still using the plugins.
P.S. this solution does not work. Skipping the tests I can avoid the creation of 'surefire-reports' not 'surefire'

Answer (score 0):

Mention exclude directories inside pom.xml file 
Inside exclude tags mention your files which you dont want.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-clean</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>target</directory>
                                <excludes>
                                   <exclude></exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```